# select option randomly by jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, html-select

For a form i am on the way to add a button that fills / selects some random data (for testing purposes) on click. For that I've created some functions for input elements. For select lists i would like to do something like this:

```
$form.find("select").each(function(){
        let optionsCount = $(this).find('option').length;
        index = getRandomArbitrary(1,optionsCount-1);
        $(this+' :nth-child('+index+')').prop('selected', true); // $(this+' :nth-child('+index+')') is not valid
    });
```

That should randomly select one option of the list - and yes the code above does not work but I have no clue how I could write such a function to "select option randomly by jQuery".

I mean the main issue is that we cannot mix $(this) with a pseudo and i don't know how to extend / change the selector away from $(this).

Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, you cannot concatenate the `this` element reference to a selector string in a jQuery object. The solution to this issue is to use the `eq()` method to find the child `option` of each `select` by the generated random index. Try this:

```js
let $form = $('form');

$('.random').on('click', () => {
  $form.find("select").each((i, el) => {
    let $options = $(el).find('option');
    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * $options.length);
    $options.eq(index).prop('selected', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <button type="button" class="random">Select random</button>

  <select>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
    <option>E</option>
    <option>F</option>
    <option>G</option>
  </select>

  <select>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
    <option>E</option>
    <option>F</option>
    <option>G</option>
  </select>

  <select>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
    <option>E</option>
    <option>F</option>
    <option>G</option>
  </select>
</form>
```